# Autoit - limiting the number of execution

Tags: user-interface, time, limit, autoit

I don't know if it's possible cuz i couldn't find anywhere.
I have created a GUI with some buttons to start things.

I'm just wondering if it is possible to:

1. limit the number of openings of the GUI
2. limit the number of executions with the buttons
3. limit the time range so that after certain point, u can't use it

Global $explain = "help~~"

```
#include <IE.au3>
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <StaticConstants.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

Global $explain = "hmmm"
Global $Form1 = GUICreate("Yay", 328, 157)
Global $Label1 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("ID", 12, 14, 67, 20)
Global $Label2 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Password", 12, 44, 67, 20)
Global $Label3 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("hello world", 225, 14, 90, 20)
Global $Input1 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 76, 10, 105, 24)
Global $Input2 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 76, 40, 105, 24, BitOR($ES_PASSWORD, $ES_AUTOHSCROLL))
Global $Input3 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 228, 40, 70, 24)
Global $Button1 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Log In", 76, 69, 105, 30)
Global $Button2 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Connect", 212, 69, 100, 30)
Global $Checkbox1 = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox("hmm", 240, 113, 97, 17)
Global $Checkbox2 = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox("hmm2", 240, 134, 97, 17)

Global $Group1 = GUICtrlCreateGroup("", 5, -5, 190, 110)
Global $Edit1 = GUICtrlCreateEdit("", 5, 110, 228, 100)
GUICtrlSetData(-1, $explain)

GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

While 1
$nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
Switch $nMsg
    Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
        Exit
    Case $Checkbox1
        If (GUICtrlRead($Checkbox1) = $GUI_CHECKED) Then
            Global $hmm = 1
        EndIf
    Case $Checkbox2
        If (GUICtrlRead($Checkbox2) = $GUI_CHECKED) Then
            Global $hmm2 = 0
        EndIf
    Case $Button1
        Global $id = GUICtrlRead($Input1)
        Global $pass = GUICtrlRead($Input2)
        WinSetState("Yay", "", @SW_MINIMIZE)
        MsgBox(0,"","possible to limit #of Execution?")
    Case $Button2
        Global $exnum = GUICtrlRead($Input3)
        WinSetState("Yay", "", @SW_MINIMIZE)
        MsgBox(0,"","time limit would be nice too! thnx!")
EndSwitch
WEnd
```

Has anyone tried this? 
Will it require intense coding? 
Could you provide a sample if it isn't too bad

Comment: Could you elaborate what this script is supposed to do? What do you mean with "openings of the GUI"? The number how often this script is started or how many instances of the script can be started at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon Pita,

Yup! It's all definitely possible to do! There's multiple ways to do so, I'll try to name a few.

A good way for you to manage these requests, would be to make a properties file to manage everything. Take a look at my example below!

```
Global $explain = "help~~"

#include <IE.au3>
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <StaticConstants.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

; =================================================================================================================================================
#include <File.au3>
#Include <Date.au3>

; This is the directory that the temporary file will be stored.
$fileHandle = @AppDataDir & "\TestProgram\properties.txt"

; Checks to see if the properties file exists
if FileExists($fileHandle) Then
    ; START Check Run Limit
    ; Reads the first value in the properties file. In this example, it's the limit to how many times the program can be launched.
    $runLimit = FileReadLine($fileHandle, 1)
    ; MsgBox(0,"Run Limit", $runLimit)
    ; If the run limit reaches zero (or less than by some glitch), do not launch the program.
    if $runLimit <= 0 Then
        MsgBox(16,"Run Limit Reached", "You have reached the maximum number of launches for this program!")
        Exit
    EndIf
    ; Subtract one from the launch limit.
    $newLimit = $runLimit - 1
    MsgBox(0,"New Run Limit", "You may launch this program " & $newLimit & " more times!", 3)
    ; Update the properties file.
    _FileWriteToLine($fileHandle, 1, $newLimit, True)
    ; END Check Run Limit

    ; Start CHECK Expiration Date
    $expDate = FileReadLine($fileHandle, 2)
    ; MsgBox(0,"Expiration Date", "This program expires on " & $expDate)
    ; Check to see if the expiration date has already passed
    if $expDate < _NowDate() Then
        MsgBox(16,"Program Expired","Your trial period has expired!")
        Exit
    EndIf

    ; END Check expiration date
Else
    ; If the file does not exists, create it and set it up
    $propFile = FileOpen($fileHandle, 10)
    ; Sets the launch limit to 10. Change this value to set the launch limit
    FileWrite($fileHandle, "10" & @CRLF)
    ; Sets the expiration date to a week (7 days) from the initial launch date.
    FileWrite($fileHandle, @MON & "/" & (@MDAY + 7) & "/" & @YEAR & @CRLF)
    ; Sets the button limit for the login button to 3.
    FileWrite($fileHandle, "3" & @CRLF)
    FileClose($fileHandle)

    #CS
        NOTE: THIS IS JUST FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES! THE USER CAN SIMPLY DELETE THE PROPERTIES FILE
            IN ORDER TO RESET THE VALUES AND CONTINUE USING THE PROGRAM. THIS WAS DESIGNED SIMPLY TO
            GET YOU ON THE RIGHT TRACK.
    #CE
EndIf



; =================================================================================================================================================

Global $explain = "hmmm"
Global $Form1 = GUICreate("Yay", 328, 157)
Global $Label1 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("ID", 12, 14, 67, 20)
Global $Label2 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Password", 12, 44, 67, 20)
Global $Label3 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("hello world", 225, 14, 90, 20)
Global $Input1 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 76, 10, 105, 24)
Global $Input2 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 76, 40, 105, 24, BitOR($ES_PASSWORD, $ES_AUTOHSCROLL))
Global $Input3 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 228, 40, 70, 24)
Global $Button1 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Log In", 76, 69, 105, 30)
Global $Button2 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Connect", 212, 69, 100, 30)
Global $Checkbox1 = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox("hmm", 240, 113, 97, 17)
Global $Checkbox2 = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox("hmm2", 240, 134, 97, 17)

Global $Group1 = GUICtrlCreateGroup("", 5, -5, 190, 110)
Global $Edit1 = GUICtrlCreateEdit("", 5, 110, 228, 100)
GUICtrlSetData(-1, $explain)

GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

While 1
$nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
Switch $nMsg
    Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
        Exit
    Case $Checkbox1
        If (GUICtrlRead($Checkbox1) = $GUI_CHECKED) Then
            Global $hmm = 1
        EndIf
    Case $Checkbox2
        If (GUICtrlRead($Checkbox2) = $GUI_CHECKED) Then
            Global $hmm2 = 0
        EndIf
    Case $Button1
        ; START Button Limit ================================================================================================================
        if FileExists($fileHandle) Then
            $buttonLimit = FileReadLine($fileHandle, 3)
            if $buttonLimit <= 0 Then
                MsgBox(16,"Button Limit Reached", "You have reached the maximum number of times you can hit this button!")
            ELSE
                $newButtonLimit = $buttonLimit - 1
                MsgBox(0,"New Run Limit", "You may press this button " & $newButtonLimit & " more times!", 3)
                _FileWriteToLine($fileHandle, 3, $newButtonLimit, True)

                ; START OLD CODE
                Global $id = GUICtrlRead($Input1)
                Global $pass = GUICtrlRead($Input2)
                ; WinSetState("Yay", "", @SW_MINIMIZE)
                MsgBox(0,"","possible to limit #of Execution?")
                ; END OLD CODE ================================================================================================================

            EndIf
        EndIf
        ; END Button Limit
    Case $Button2
        Global $exnum = GUICtrlRead($Input3)
        WinSetState("Yay", "", @SW_MINIMIZE)
        MsgBox(0,"","time limit would be nice too! thnx!")
EndSwitch
WEnd
```

Upon launching the program, a property file is generated and stored in the appdata on the users computer.

> On windows: Press Win+R and type %appdata%. If you left the example the same, there will be a folder called "TestProgram", if you changed the name, it will be whatever you called it. Inside of this folder, there will be the properties.txt file (Again, unless you changed the name).

I have made some comments in the example code to help explain what I did, but I'm not fantastic at explaining things so please let me know if you need some more help.

P.S. If you do use this method, I strongly suggest encrypting (Using [Crypt](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Crypt_EncryptData.htm) maybe?) the properties file to make it a little less editable and designing some way to tell if the user deleted the file.

I hope this helps!,

Tim